# Pytest doest not see @pytest.fixture

Tags: python, selenium, pytest

I have two classes with fixtures, but they don't see each other. Can anybody help me to figure out why it's not working? Please!

> def test_home_page(self):
> E       fixture 'before_start' not found
> available fixtures: cache, capfd, capfdbinary, caplog, capsys, capsysbinary, doctest_namespace, monkeypatch, pytestconfig, record_property, record_testsuite_property, record_xml_attribute, recwarn, tmp_path, tmp_path_factory, tmpdir, tmpdir_factory
> use 'pytest --fixtures [testpath]' for help on them.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------
conftest.py

import pytest
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service


@pytest.fixture(scope="class")
    def before_start(request):
        s = Service('/Users/******/PycharmProjects/Framework/chromedriver')
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)
        driver.get("https://www.keurig.com/")
        driver.maximize_window()
        driver.implicitly_wait(10)
        request.cls.driver = driver
        yield
        driver.close()

---------------------------------------------------------------------
test_home_page.py

import pytest
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


@pytest.mark.usefixtures("before_start")
class TestHomePage():
    def test_home_page(self):
        self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//input[@id="couponsSignup"]').send_keys("*****")

        self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//input[@id ="popup_signupbutton"]').click()

        self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="_tealiumModalClose"]').click()
```

Comment: It's probably not recognizing it because of the request parameter... where is that supposed to come from?  Also why are your imports split like that and why import pytest twice, and Why are you using a class for TestHomePage?

Comment: I'm guessing that you are showing two different modules, and by "classes" you mean "modules". Put your fixture into `conftest.py` to make it visible to the tests.

Comment: @Alexander there are two classes, where the import starts it's a new class. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @MrBeanBremen, there are two classes: contest.py and test_home_page.py.
 contest.py has def before_start, and  test_home_page.py has to use it.

Comment: @Tetiana - can you please adapt the original question to make clear which code is in which module? Also what is the second class you mentioned? You are showing only `TestHomePage`.

Comment: @MrBeanBremen, there are two classes: class TestHomePage(): and class ContestBeforeTest(): and TestHomePage has to use ContestBeforeTest method def before_start

Comment: Hm, why is your fixture inside a class? I don't see how this would work. Your first version (without the class) looked more like it. Also, I understand that the fixture is in `conftest.py`, and the test in a separate module, right?

Comment: @MrBeanBremen I added just now to see if it's correct. Before, it was without any class.

Comment: @MrBeanBremen, yes, the fixture is in conftest.py. I have to use its "before_start". To run driver in the class TestHomePage():

Comment: That should actually work, provided `conftest.py` is in the same path as the test, or higher up in the module hierarchy. It would help, if you could add the file names and paths for your code.

Comment: @MrBeanBremen I figure out: I misspelled conftest.py class. Thank you. I just start working with python and pytest. Thank you for your time!